# Blazor App Run as WASM or Server. Cannot get Dependency Injection working in Server Mode

Tags: dependency-injection, server, blazor, webassembly

I've read numerous articles on switching between WASM and Server modes in a single app.  The one that matched closest to my requirements is:  https://itnext.io/blazor-switching-server-and-webassembly-at-runtime-d65c25fd4d8

I'm trying to set my project up so that I can develop in Server mode due to better debugging etc. and deploy using WebAssembly.  To isolate the problem that I've been facing, I've created this github repo based upon a standard WebAssembly (hosted) template.   https://github.com/gwruck/Blazor_WASM_Server.  See the Readme file for details.

The solution works fine in WebAssembly mode, but in Server mode, I get an error: "InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'api' on type 'Blazor_WASM_Server.Client.Pages.Index'. There is no registered service of type 'Blazor_WASM_Server.Client.WebApiClient'.

I have created a Typed Http Client in the Client app (WebApiClient) and injected it into the Index page.  I've also tried injecting a number of other services as well, but I can't seem to get any of them to work in Server mode.

Based upon this article, I thought that this approach would work.  https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/call-rest-api-from-blazor/

I understand that the treatment of DI is different between WASM and Server, but I can't get it to work at all in this scenario.  Is this a fundamental limitation of trying to combine the 2 types of  Blazor, or can anyone see a way around this?  Let me know if you need more info to describe the problem.

Following are key elements of code:

Blazor_WASM_Server.Server

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="6.0.0-preview.5.21301.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0-preview.5.21301.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Client\Blazor_WASM_Server.Client.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\Blazor_WASM_Server.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

namespace Blazor_WASM_Server.Server
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }

   public enum HybridType
    {
        ServerSide,
        WebAssembly//,
    }
    public class HybridOptions
    {
        //Choose WebAssembly or ServerSide
        public HybridType HybridType { get; set; } = HybridType.ServerSide;
    }
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public HybridOptions hybridOptions = new HybridOptions();

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
           

        if (hybridOptions.HybridType == HybridType.ServerSide)
        {
            //Conditionally add ServerSide
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();//new}
        }
        services.Configure<HybridOptions>(Configuration);
    }
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
}

_Host.cshtml

@page "_Host"
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@using Blazor_WASM_Server.Server
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@using Blazor_WASM_Server.Client

@inject IOptions<HybridOptions> HybridOptions
@{
    @*Retrieve the running mode*@
    var hybridType = HybridOptions?.Value?.HybridType ?? HybridType.WebAssembly;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Sabre PM</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes/bootstrap4.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    **@*Conditionally apply Server/Webassembly.  This is where the magic happens*@**
    @if (hybridType == HybridType.ServerSide)
    {
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered"/>
        <persist-component-state/>
        <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    }
    else if (hybridType == HybridType.WebAssembly)
    {
        <div id="app">Loading...</div>
        <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    }

</div>
    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Blazor_WASM_Server.Client

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.0-preview.5.21301.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.0-preview.5.21301.17" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0-preview.5.21301.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="6.0.0-preview.5.21301.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\Blazor_WASM_Server.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

 public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<Client.App>("#app");

            //Added a typed Http client
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient<WebApiClient>(client =>    
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            });

            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
    }

public class WebApiClient
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; }

    public WebApiClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }
}

@* Index.razor *@
@page "/"

@inject WebApiClient api

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code{

    //Inject the WebApiClient and verify it has been set
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
         **//For some reason, whatever I try to inject here will work in WASM Mode, but not in SeverSide mode**
        if (api == null) throw new NullReferenceException("WebApiClient not set by Dependency Injection");

        base.OnInitialized();
    }

}
```

I know this is mixing and matching paradigms a lot, but very similar code will work in a "pure" serverside app if you set it up to read a Web API.  I just can't work out why it won't work in this blended version.  I suspect it's got something to do with the project type (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly vs Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web

I realise this is a "big" question, but hopefully this distills it down to the key elements.  I suspect there is something fundamental missing in the architecture that I'm overlooking.

Comment: When the Server Mode has problems it makes more sense to post that code. Startup.cs and Program.cs for a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated After Reviewing your Repo**

You need to register a HttpClient in your Blazor Server Startup

Your startup.cs in *Blazor_WASM_Server.Server* should look like this:

```
using Blazor_WASM_Server.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace Blazor_WASM_Server.Server
{
    public enum HybridType
    {
        ServerSide,
        WebAssembly//,
        //HybridManual,
        //HybridOnNavigation,
        //HybridOnReady
    }
    public class HybridOptions
    {
        public HybridType HybridType { get; set; } = HybridType.ServerSide;
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public HybridOptions hybridOptions = new HybridOptions();

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();



            if (hybridOptions.HybridType == HybridType.ServerSide)
            {
                services.AddServerSideBlazor();
                // Server Side Blazor doesn't register HttpClient by default
                // Thanks to Robin Sue - Suchiman https://github.com/Suchiman/BlazorDualMode
                if (!services.Any(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(HttpClient)))
                {
                    // Setup HttpClient for server side in a client side compatible fashion
                    services.AddScoped<HttpClient>(s =>
                    {
                        // Creating the URI helper needs to wait until the JS Runtime is initialized, so defer it.
                        var uriHelper = s.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
                        return new HttpClient
                        {
                            BaseAddress = new Uri(uriHelper.BaseUri)
                        };
                    });
                }
                services.AddScoped<WebApiClient>();
            }
            services.Configure<HybridOptions>(Configuration);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You can see my own take on the combined site at https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/AllinOne,

Comment: Wow -that was the nugget I was missing.  I had seen Robin Sue's work, but must admit I missed that part. I hadn't seen yours before - will study it now.  Hopefully this thread helps someone else avoid the rabbit hole I have just been down!!!

Comment: NP. :-)  Going down dark holes and shooting oneself in the foot are common practices in coding!

Comment: Thanks again for this.  I was "aware" that WASM ran in browser and Server ran on server, but the subtlety of where to register the services was lost on me - even after many hours of research.  The closest I could get from MS is on this link, but it doesn't really get to the bottom of it IMHO.  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server).